# In choosing a keyhole contour to compute a complex valued integral, is the inner loop positively oriented?

Tags: complex-analysis

If the outer circle starts in a counterclockwise direction, i.e., positively oriented, and turns into the straight line, which turns into a small circle (a loop, technically, since it doesn't fully close into a circle) that goes clockwise to connect the second straight line that closes the keyhole contour, is the small circle considered positively oriented -- even though it is being traversed *clockwise*.

Not that it matters too much, since in computing the integral using residues, the integral on the small circle should go to zero.

Thanks,

EDIT:  I'm guessing the answer is "yes", since the region is again to the left of the contour that is being traced out, and this usually the convention for positively oriented contours, but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule of thumb is that positive orientation on boundary of set $U$ is such that its interior is on left as you are passing through. In other words, pair (outer normal to $U$, tangent to curve) is positively oriented.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Blazej.